# Testing Actor without timers

Tags: scala, akka

First of all, I am a beginner in Akka. I have an `Actor` (in Scala), which after receiving a message:

- may not send anything
- may send a message
- may send multiple messages

I would like to test it, without the need for timers.

As far as I managed to dig, I can use the `?` function of a `TestActorRef`, then wait for the `Future`. I don't know if this will time out if nothing is sent (I suspect it will, because it has an implicit timeout parameter), but it can't wait for multiple messages.

I can also use the `recieve` functions in the `TestKit`, however that will time out when it ensures that no message is received, which will make my tests slow and less robust.

What I need (or I think I need), is something that can send in messages, then run receive on the `Actor` until there are messages in its message queue, then check what it has sent out.

Can you tell me a way to achieve this, or point out what should I do in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

You should use http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html#Synchronous_Unit_Testing_with_TestActorRef
Documentation there is pretty good.

Comment: AskPattern (? function) shown there, which is not able to receive multiple messages. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Well, it will work with multiple messages. If you look at the example with ask you will see that `future` was returned immediately, i.e. behaviour is synchronous and fully deterministic. Also note that sync testing is not recommended, what's wrong with timers?